# Slide Down & Slide Up

Tags: jquery

I am using Slide down & Up it's working fine. But my problem is when user open this page it slide Up if user click then only slide down.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $(".block-layered-nav dt").click(function () {
            if ($(this).next("dd").css("display") == "none") {
                $(this).next("dd").slideDown(1000);
                $(this).removeClass("closed");
            } else {
                $(this).next("dd").slideUp(1000);
                $(this).addClass("closed");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

What mistake i done

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: When user click then only it open but now whenever we open this page it always open

Comment: Please put this into a jsfiddle and we can go from there

Comment: Sorry i am not getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Add class `closed` with the element

**Working Demo**

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('dd').hide()
  $(".navigation dt").click(function() {
    if ($(this).next('dd').is(":visible")) {
      $(this).next('dd').slideToggle('slow').toggleClass('close');
    } else {
      $(this).next('dd').slideToggle('slow').toggleClass('close');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigation">
  <dt>test</dt>
  <dd class="close">sample</dd>
</div>
```

Comment: No Actually whenever load first time it should be not if click then only it open

Comment: @Kothari I have updated  the answer. Please verify it

Comment: Thanks for smooth slideUp(1000) i need to increase / decrease

Comment: @Kothari For smooth slideup you can increase the delay

Comment: I made it 10000 still same speed

Comment: @Kothari It is because you are adding the class `close`. At that time it is getting hidden

Comment: Okay but i need a class because i want to add some arrow button so that i am using the class

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `$.fn.slideToggle()` and `$.fn.toggleClass()` to resolve state detection problem. Solution:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".navigation dt").click(function() {
    $(this).next('dd').stop(true, false).slideToggle().toggleClass('close');
  });
});
```

```css
.closed {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigation">
  <dt>test</dt>
  <dd class="closed">sample</dd>
</div>
```

You just need to be sure of initial state of the class and CSS display attribute. And, also added `$.fn.stop()` function to avoid animation glitches.

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="jquery.js">
    </script>
</head>

<body >
<div class="test4" style="border: 1px solid black;">

<h1>Hi </h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas ducimus, animi provident laudantium necessitatibus odit. Qui quam iusto optio libero cum, nemo perferendis rerum veritatis expedita, est totam dolore natus!</p>
</div>

    <div  class="test1">    
        <button>Show Button</button>
    <button id="test">Button 2</button>
</div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("button").click(function(){

$("$test4").slideToggle();


});

$("#test").click(function()
{

    $("#test4").slideDown();
});     
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```